# How can I make the TopNav in a Shiny dashboard not overlap with the sidebar?

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a shiny dashboard with many tabs - now there are enough tabs that when the window size is small enough, the tabs wrap into a second row. For some reason, this second row overlaps the content of my sidebar, but the content in my main panel adjusts to accomodate the navbar's new size.

```
ui11 <- shinyUI(navbarPage("Beasts of Bellevue",

                           tabPanel("Head to Head", fluid = TRUE,
                                    useShinydashboard(),
                                    dashboardSidebar(
                                      sidebarMenu(),
                                      
                                      
                                      # Select variable for left plot
                                      selectInput(inputId = "left", 
                                                  label = "Manager 1:",
                                                  choices = c("Kevin", "Jake", "Lyons",
                                                              "Nipples", "Dan", "Shuds",
                                                              "Karp", "Mills", "Joey",
                                                              "Raffy", "Oster", "Scott", "Sam"), 
                                                  selected = "Kevin"),
                                      
                                      # Select variable for right plot
                                      selectInput(inputId = "right", 
                                                  label = "Manager 2:",
                                                  choices = c("Kevin", "Jake", "Lyons",
                                                              "Nipples", "Dan", "Shuds",
                                                              "Karp", "Mills", "Joey",
                                                              "Raffy", "Oster", "Scott", "Sam"), 
                                                  selected = "Lyons"),
                                      
                                      # Select which game type to include
                                      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "selected_gametype",
                                                         label = "Select game type(s):",
                                                         choices = c("Regular Season", "Playoffs", "Consolation"),
                                                         selected = c("Regular Season", "Playoffs", "Consolation")),
                                      
                                      # Select which seasons to include
                                      sliderInput(inputId = "slider", 
                                                  label = "Seasons", 
                                                  min = 2012, 
                                                  max = max(h2h$Year),
                                                  value = c(2012, max(h2h$Year)),
                                                  sep = "",
                                                  ticks = FALSE,
                                                  dragRange = TRUE),
                                      
                                      br(),
                                      
                                      tags$img(src = "bob.png", height = 225, width = 225)),
                                    
                                    #Header
                                    
                                    header <- dashboardHeader(
                                      disable = TRUE
                                    ),
                                    mainPanel(width = 12, 
                                              dashboardBody(tags$head(tags$meta(name = "viewport", content = "width=1600")),
                                                            shinyDashboardThemes(
                                                              theme = "grey_light"
                                                            ),
                                                            fluidRow(
                                                              # Row 1, Column 1
                                                              column(width = 6,
                                                                     h3(textOutput("left"))
                                                              ),
                                                              #Row 1, Column 2
                                                              column(width = 6,
                                                                     h3(textOutput("right"))
                                                              )
                                                            ),
                                                            
                                                            fluidRow(
                                                              # Row 2, Column 1
                                                              column(width = 6,
                                                                     withLoader(valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "leftnumber",
                                                                       width = NULL), type = "html", loader = "loader7")),
                                                              # Row 2, Column 2
                                                              column(width = 6,
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "rightnumber",
                                                                       width = NULL))
                                                            ),
                                                            fluidRow(
                                                              column(width = 12,
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "leftnumberavg",
                                                                       width = 2),
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "leftnumberavg2",
                                                                       width = 2),
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "leftmargofvic",
                                                                       width = 2),
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "rightnumberavg",
                                                                       width = 2),
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "rightnumberavg2",
                                                                       width = 2),
                                                                     valueBoxOutput(
                                                                       outputId = "rightmargofvic",
                                                                       width = 2))
                                                            ),
                                                            plotlyOutput(outputId = "plot")
                                              )
                                    )
                           )))
```

Here is an image of how the issue renders: [Overlapping navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mh2et.png)

Comment: Your screenshot looks like the navbar is **not** overlapping the sidebar. I don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Has there been a solution yet? I have the same with overlapping header on the controlbar